# ssh & perl & running in the background

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, aix

Both host are *nix

On host two there are two perl scripts `nfs1` and `nfs2`.

The script `nfs1` runs script `nfs2` multiple times in the background

```
system("/usr/local/scripts/nfs2 -m $mountpt &");
```

When run locally, it works just fine.

When run on a different host via ssh

```
ssh testhost /usr/local/bin/nfs1
```

ssh will wait until the script(s) `nfs2` have completed

To test I added to `nfs2` a sleep of 10 seconds.

running `nfs1` takes 'zero' time, and you can see via ps `nfs2` running then ending 10 seconds later.

When I `ssh /usr/local/scripts/nfs1` it takes 10.8 seconds, changing the sleep to 5, get me 5.8 seconds. I'll figure out the .8 later.

Ideas ?

-pete

Comment: can you please paste samples from `nfs1` and `nfs2`

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the script nfs2 has file descriptors open on the ssh link.  Close them.  Either rewrite nfs2 so that it properly daemonizes itself and closes all of its file descriptors, or modify nfs1 to call it with the descriptors closed or redirected.  That is:

```
system("/usr/local/scripts/nfs2 -m $mountpt < /dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```